# Checking if A objects property exist

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I was wanted to ask a question cause I can't really find what I'm looking for online. I want to see/check if a student `IdNum` already exist for example.

I don't know the right term that I'm looking for to google it, and the book I have isn't really that useful as to what to do when needing to do this sort of check.

Here is the code what i have been tried so far :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Class1[] c1 = new Class1[10]
    for (int i = 0; i < c1.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("enter Student ID");
        string text = Console.ReadLine();
        int value;
        while (!Int32.TryParse(text, out value))
        {
           Console.WriteLine("ID Was not a Valid ID Number. Try Again");
           text = Console.ReadLine();

        }
        // maybe here say if IdNum exist or not
        {
           // Try a different number
        }                
    }
}

Class Class1
{
    public int IdNum { get; set; }
    public int SomethingElse { get; set; }
    // and so on
}
```

Thanks

Comment: maybe  what you want is if( IdNum!=Null){ // do something }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<Class1> c1 = GetStudents();
string text = Console.ReadLine();
int value;
while (!Int32.TryParse(text, out value))
{
    Console.WriteLine("ID Was not a Valid ID Number. Try Again");
    text = Console.ReadLine();
}    
bool exist = c1.Any(s = > s.IdNum == value);
```

If you don't want to use linq, you can just rewrite the last line with:

```
bool exist = false;
foreach (var s in c1)
{
    if (s.IdNum == value)
    {
        exist = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: True that would work, but is there another way without using System.Linq? Sadly For this Can't use it

Comment: Thanks, was focusing on doing it a particular way that i just forgot about foreach loop.